# query to get every user data belong

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to write Query Set that show every User Own IPs and Asset_Names

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Asset(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    IP = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    Asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want every user see details(IP,Asset_Name) in own user Profile

The problem comes when trying to query the database, and using a string compared to an auth.User object. I do not know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter `Asset` based on the username you can do something like the following:

```
Asset.objects.filter(user__username='something')
```